# Why am i getting a missing 'end' for mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Been trying to figure why this is not compiling and giving me an error. It has to be something simple. I have a SP that accepts five parameters, sets the description to empty string and the date_added to today. Want to call the sp and insert a row into the table.

here is my code:

```
delimiter //

create procedure insert_products 
(
    category_id_param       int,
    product_code_param      varchar(10),
    product_name_param      varchar(255),
    list_price_param        decimal(10,2),
    discount_percent_param  decimal(10,2)
)

begin
    declare description_var     text;
    declare date_added_var      datetime;

--validate parameters
if list_price_param < 0 then
    signal sqlstate '22003'
      set message_text = 'List price must be positive number',
      mysql_errno = 1264;

elseif discount_price_param < 0 then 
    signal sqlstate '22003'
        set message_text = 'Discount percent cannot be negative',
        mysql_errno = 1264;
end if;


--set variable
set description_var = '';
set date_added_var = now();

insert into products
    values(default, category_id_param, product_code_param,      
           product_name_param,description_var, list_price_param, 
           discount_percent_param, date_added_var);

end//

delimiter ;

call insert_products(33, 100, 'jet ski', 25.66, .30);
```

Comment: How are you trying to run this batch?

Comment: I wanted to create the procedure and coded the call just to test the error handling.

Comment: Nothing is jumping out.  You don't need the local variables - you can just use the function call and constant directly in the insert.  I'd suggest reducing the sproc to an empty body, see if that works, and start adding things in until it fails  to create.

Comment: yeah, that is what is driving me crazy. I'm going to put it away for the night and jump back on it tomorrow. Reassuring knowing the code is correct.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's right.  I'd just say that I can't see what's wrong just from reading it. :)

Comment: *"giving me an error"*  Please remember to include the exact error string.

Comment: You can simply find sql-syntax-errors in scripts with a [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). Add text into SqlDocument, and Syntax Check will show errors in Error List and in script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add white space after the `--` in comments.

```
--validate parameters
```

should be like this:

```
-- validate parameters
```

More information about the comments - [Comment Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html).

Comment: How simple and so hard to spot. There is now a error code of 1452. This is because the category_id should be updated from categories table. How is it possible to update that table column first with the parameters and then add the row to my products table. I want to add one row to products and cannot until categories is updated

Comment: Error 1452 is connected with foreign key. And there is a rule - firstly add ID value to parent table, then add it to a child table.

Comment: There is a work around, you can firstly add value to the child table, then to the parent, using FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS system variable.

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove:

```
delimiter //
```

and

```
//
delimiter
```

also specify the columnNames of:

```
insert into products (column1,column2,column3,...)values()
```

Third option:

**from**

```
end//
```

**To:**

```
end;//
```

Comment: Nether of these are problems (unless the insert doesn't specify enough values for every column)